# Does Authorization using a OAuth access token work for CometD?

Tags: api, cometd

I keep getting a 401 response from the handshake end point https://na73.lightning.force.com/cometd/39.0/handshake after making a post request with the following header setting

Authorization:Bearer *access_token*

Does CometD support OAuth? If so can you provide a full example of using the Java EMP-Connector for cometd?

```
[
    {
        "ext": {
            "sfdc": {
                "failureReason": "401::Authentication invalid"
            },
            "replay": true,
            "payload.format": true
        },
        "advice": {
            "reconnect": "none"
        },
        "channel": "/meta/handshake",
        "id": "1",
        "error": "403::Handshake denied",
        "successful": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Forget it the HOST in the URL is wrong https://na73.salesforce.com should be used instead of https://na73.lightning.force.com/